# Handling all HTTP errors (4xx/5xx) in global.asax file

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, global-asax, http-error

How can I get HTTP errors to go through the `Application_Error` method of the global.asax file? Testing with errors such as 403 and 404, it always defaults to IIS' errors. I added

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

to my web.config file and that has stopped the IIS errors, but that still doesn't go through the `Application_Error` method of the global.asax.

Is there anyway for all HTTP errors to be handled by global.asax? I'm using .NET 4.5 web forms w/ routing for URL re-writing and IIS8 on Win 2012.

Comment: Check this out http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_debugging/article.php/c19411/Web-Application-Error-Handling-in-ASPNET.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand the error handling, the problem is that the HTTP errors never hit the `Application_Error` method in the global.asax or the OnError method of the page.

Comment: Exactly. For this you need to go into HTTP stack and write custom code

Comment: Do you have an example of this? I'm not sure how to do that? I looked in that article but didn't see anything like that.

Comment: This is complicated stuff: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp
But I know people who customized HTTP pipeline. 
With new MVC, Web Api, this is all so easy - you can write a custom handler and do anything you want. But in Asp.net it is more complicated